# Angular Material CDK Drag and Drop Snap To Grid Internal Element cdkDragConstrainPosition @Input for element inside the Drag and Drop element position

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

When using Drag and Drop via Angular Material CDK, it allows you to "snap to grid" via `[cdkDragConstrainPosition]="computedDragRenderPos"`

Example:

```html
<div cdkDrag [cdkDragConstrainPosition]="computeDragRenderPos">
  ...
</div>
```

```js
export class MyDraggableComponent {

  constructor() {}

  computeDragRenderPos(pos, dragRef) {
    return {x: Math.floor(pos.x / 30) * 30, y: pos.y}; // will render the element every 30 pixels horizontally
  }
}
```

However, that passes in pos which is the mouse pos.  I understand you can pass dragRef and get the element's getBoundingClientRect to get the x but as soon as you pass that into the `cdkDragConstrainPosition` position and change the position of the element it no longer works.

How do you move an internal element every 30px.... and not the position of the start of the element?

Comment: Did you find out how to solve this? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

i have close issue

dragRef it is a ref to dragable element if you want snap to some grid you need to calculate position depend on other element

```
@ViewChild("someElement") someElement;

computeDragRenderPos(pos, dragRef) {
    return {
       x: this.someElement.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().x,
       y: this.someElement.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().y };
  }
```

you need to include some cursor logic here to keep it work

in my case it is also lost scope of the component class for some reason (not sure it was personal problem or global) i solve it with `bind(this)` before pass function  to `cdkDragConstrainPosition`

Comment: I am having this same issue with the scope. Can you explain how you used bind(this) so you can access component scoped variables in this method?

Comment: @ChrisKooken You can use it like this `[cdkDragConstrainPosition]="computeDragRenderPos.bind(this)"`.

Comment: @vinger What logic did you use, to keep the dragging work? I could not manage to get the dragging working after using the top left position of the element and not the cursor position. I mean the cursor position is still tracked and updated, but the element does not move anymore. I simply don't understand why that happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way:

```html
<div cdkDrag 
    (cdkDragStarted)="dragStarted($event)>
    [cdkDragConstrainPosition]="computeDragRenderPos.bind(this)"
  ...
</div>
```

```js
/** Initial position */
start;


dragStarted(event: CdkDragStart) {
    this.start = event.source.element.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
}


computeDragRenderPos(pos, dragRef) {
    // will render the element every 30 pixels horizontally
    const delta = pos.x - this.start.x;
    return {x: start.x + Math.floor(delta / 30) * 30, y: this.start.y};
}
```